# How to print \upharpoonright?

Tags: relation-symbols

When I run `pdflatex` twice on my LaTeX file, the command `\upharpoonright` does not print the harpoon. Could you let me know how to fix this.
I use this command `$ S(T)\upharpoonright D^{i}_{l} $`.

Comment: have you some exemple to show. It's hard to know what is the problem without it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As Romain says, you should create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 5):

You need a package that provides `\upharpoonright`, e.g. `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
  $ S(T)\upharpoonright D^{i}_{l} $
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, there was a conflit between  \usepackage{amssymb} and \input{Amssym.def}
\input{Amssym} that was just before the definition.  Removing those two, it did work. Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, it is not necessary to use `\input{amssym.def}` or any related file at all. Use `\input` basically only for portions of your own `.tex` code, e.g. one `.tex` file for each chapter etc.

Comment: @MBekkali: `amssym.def` and `amssym.tex` are files for *plain TeX* users. Package `amssymb` (`\usepackage{amssymb}`)  should be used in LaTeX.